# referencing jQuery created element, to register a click (with fiddle)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a project which would require the user to be able to add, and edit tags.

On the page, is: a div container, containing the tags, a textbox (newTag) and a button (add tag) that will add a tag to the container. Another textbox (editTag) and a button (update tag) that will update the tag information typed in by the user. There is also a select list that will, in realtime - keep track of all the changes made.

Wen a user clicks on a tag that was already rendered, to edit it - all works well. The tag name goes into the edit textbox, and the tag is selected in the list.

The problem arises when a user created tag gets clicked... nothing happens. I have a feeling it has to do with the fact the object is in the DOM, but isn't rendered HTML. But I have no clue as to how to resolve this issue - how to reference a click of a dom object.

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
        <!-- tags container -->
        <div class="container_12">
            <div class="grid_2"><img src="images/spacer.png" /></div>
            <div id="content" class="grid_8">
                <button name="PHP" class="tag-button">PHP</button>
                <button name="CSS" class="tag-button">CSS</button>

            </div>
            <div class="grid_2"><img src="images/spacer.png" /></div>
        </div>
        <!-- tags container end -->

        <!-- action buttons container -->
        <div class="container_12 action-bar">
            <div class="grid_4"><img src="images/spacer.png" /></div>
            <div id="action-add">
                <input type="text" name="newTag" id="newTag" />
                <input type="button" id="add" value="Add tag" />
            </div>
            <div class="grid_4"><img src="images/spacer.png" /></div>
            <div id="action-edit">
                <input type="text" name="editTag" id="editTag" />
                <input type="button" id="update" value="Update tag" />
            </div>
        <!-- action buttons container end -->
        </div>

        <!-- Real Time list container -->
        <div class="container_12">
            <div class="grid_4"><img src="images/spacer.png" /></div>
            <select id="insertString">
                <option value="0">PHP</option>
                <option value="1">CSS</option>
            </select>
        </div>
<!-- real time list container end -->
```

jQuery:

```
        //button add click
        $('#add').click(function() {
            //creating a new tag for the tag bar
            var tag = $('#newTag').val();
            var tagHTML=$('<button name= "' + tag + '" class="tag-button">'+ tag + '</button>');
            var qString = "";
            // adding the tag to the bar
            $("#content").append(tagHTML);

            //get last value in the list
            var lastValue = $('#insertString option:last-child').val();
            if (! lastValue) {lastValue = 0;}
            else {lastValue = ++ lastValue; }
            //add new option for the new tag
            $('<option value="' + lastValue + '">' + tag + '</option>').appendTo("#insertString")
        })

        //tag button click
        $(".tag-button").click(function(){
            var name = $(this).attr('name');

            //add the tag name to the editTag textbox
            $('#editTag').val(name);

            $('#insertString option:contains("'+ name + '")').attr('selected', true);
        });
```

Also, here's my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lm3ab/

Help would be appreciate, and thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use  [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). You have to use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) using delegated-events approach.

Use

```
 $("#content").on("click", ".tag-button", function() {
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lm3ab/2/)

Comment: priceless information - I really appreciate it Satpal

Answer (score 1):

just add another click, thus

```
$("#content").on("click", ".tag-button", function(){});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lm3ab/1/

Comment: and of course, yours works as well - thank you for your time Paulo!

Answer (score 1):

Event delegation, since these tags weren't on the page at the time of the click events being binded, they have no listeners. Bind the click event to the container and target the elements:

```
$("#content").on("click", ".tag-button", function() {
```